# jquery Validation plugin with masked input, incorrectly validating phone number

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, maskedinput

I've been trying to figure out why the validation of a phone number has been triggering for a phone number field. I'm using both the [Validator plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) as well as the masked input plugins to set up some validation for a set of fields. I don't suspect that this specific issue is related to the usage of the masked input plugin, but I am mentioning it anyways.

If any of the fields (except the extension field) are filled, then all fields (except extension) are required. That code is doing what it should, but the validation is triggering an additional validation that I don't want. The phone number is doing a length check, even though I haven't coded anything where that's required.

```
        $("#requestform").validate({
        rules: {
            namedepa: {
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [6, ".section"]
            },
            techdepa: {
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [6, ".section"]
            },
            conphodepa: {
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [6, ".section"],
                maskedPhone: true
            },
            techemaildepa: {
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [6, ".section"]
            },
            adddepa: {
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [6, ".section"]
            },
            roomdepa: {
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [6, ".section"]
            }
        },
        onfocusout: function (element) {
            $(element).valid();
        },
        focusCleanup: true,
        errorClass: "error"
    });
    var ErrorMessage = "&nbsp;Required";
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        skip_or_fill_minimum: ErrorMessage,
        required: ErrorMessage
    });
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqnhC/3/) that demonstrates the issue that I'm having. If you tab through the fields, when you get to and pass the phone number field, The a "you must enter no more than 10 characters" message appears.

I'm not sure where to go from here. The JsFiddle I've created also has the maskedPhone validator that I created, though I can't see this as bieng a problem, I've tested the phone numbers I'm  using with the www.regexpal.com website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need the `onfocusout` callback function... that's the default behavior.  Also `errorClass: "error"` is the default.  [See documentation for more info](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Secondly, the error message is being triggered by the `maxlength="10"` attribute inside the phone field in combination with the masked input itself being more than 10 characters.

```
<input name="phodepa" type="text" maxlength="10" id="phodepa" class="setTelephone section"/>
```

**Your modified code:  http://jsfiddle.net/vY22J/**

I'm not entirely sure why you're using the `skip_or_fill_minimum` rule when you've selected all fields on the form as part of the rule.  When you make them all `required`, the whole form is skipped when nothing is filled out, is also the default behavior of the plugin.  I guess I'm not understanding the point in this case.

---

**EDIT**:

User beware:  There is an open Github issue on the `skip_or_fill_minimum` rule.

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412

Comment: I hadn't even remembered I had the max length on the input field. As for the other elements regarding errorclass and onfocusout, i'd included those because i had other problems earlier, but the problems are gone now, and no reason to add additional bytes to file size if not necessary. Thanks sparky!

Comment: @Frankfurt, I'm glad it's working.  `onfocusout` is one of the callbacks that can only be set to `false` OR an over-riding function.  Maybe you accidentally set it to `true`... that would have broken it.

Comment: I just provided a portion of the actual form, the actual form that i'm working with has a few more fields and there is some other business logic in place which I excluded from my question because it was unrelated to the issue at hand. The actual idea was that if any of those fields are filled in, all of them are required, if only none are filled in, skip validation of the entire section. I hope that adds some clarity to the reasoning behind my use of that specific validation method.

Comment: @Frankfurt, yes, clear, because that rule only makes sense when it's not applied to all the fields on the form.

Comment: @Frankfurt, also check out the Github for this plugin.  [Some of the additional methods, including this one, have bugs](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412).